# exporting a dataset into a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a list like this example:

```
mylist = ['chr10 30930000 32110000 ARHGAP12,PFKP,ZEB1,ZNF438 4', 'chr15 76430000 77240000 ETFA,ISL2, 4']
```

I am trying to export it into a `text file`. in fact every `string would be one line` and `every line would have 5 columns`. every `space separated part` in every string would be `one column`. so, in `column 4` there are some `comma separated characters` and they will be `in the same column`. and the file would be `tab separated`.

for the example, the expected output would look like this:

```
chr10   30930000    32110000    ARHGAP12,PFKP,ZEB1,ZNF438   4
chr15   76430000    77240000    ETFA,ISL2   4
```

i am doing that in `python` using the following code:

```
with open('outfile.txt', "w") as f:
    for item in mylist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item+ '\t')
```

but it does not return exactly what i want. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your `item` is a string e.g. `'chr10 30930000 32110000 ARHGAP12,PFKP,ZEB1,ZNF438 4'`.
I think you'd like to convert the spaces between each column values to tabs. To achive that you should add another nested loop. Something like this:

```
with open('outfile.txt', "w") as f:
    for line in mylist:
        for item in line.split(' '):
            f.write(item + '\t')
        f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
f.write("%s\n" % item+ '\t')
```

Join by tabs after splitting by whitespace:

```
f.write('\t'.join(item.split()) + '\n)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be fairly simple as follows -

```
aa=['chr10 30930000 32110000 ARHGAP12,PFKP,ZEB1,ZNF438 4', 'chr15 76430000 77240000 ETFA,ISL2, 4']
with open("aa.txt","w") as wr:
    for item in aa:
        wr.write("\t".join(item.split(" ")) + "\n")
```